# Outlook integration - Appointment send event

Tags: c#, events, outlook, outlook-addin

I have a problem with the "Send" event of the AppointmentItem of the Outlook library.

Whenever I'am trying to assign some method or action to the "Send" event, the following error is being thrown. Can somebody explain it to me or help me?

I know there HAS to be a send event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865990.aspx

[image: error in Visual Studio]

This is my code:

```
 private void btnOutlookCalendar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");
        Outlook.Application outlookApp;
        int collCount = processes.Length;

        if (collCount != 0)

        {

            // Outlook already running, hook into the Outlook instance
            outlookApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;

        }
        else
        {
            outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); //neues Outlook Objekt erzeugen
        }

        Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment;

        oAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); // neuen Kalendereintrag erstellen

        oAppointment.Subject = this.dtoEvent.Bezeichnung; // set the subject
        oAppointment.Body = "Automatisch durch das X erstelltes Event\n\n"
            + this.dtoEvent.Beschreibung + "\nWeitere Informationen:\n"
            + "X" + this.dtoEvent.ID;
        oAppointment.Location = this.dtoEvent.Ort + ", " + this.dtoEvent.Strasse; // set the location

        oAppointment.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dtoEvent.Datum_Von + " " + this.dtoEvent.Uhrzeit_Von); // Set the start date 
        oAppointment.End = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dtoEvent.Datum_Bis + " " + this.dtoEvent.Uhrzeit_Bis); // End date             

        oAppointment.ReminderSet = true; // Set the reminder
        oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15; // reminder time
        oAppointment.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; // appointment importance
        oAppointment.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;

        this.oAppointment = oAppointment; 

        oAppointment.Display(true);

        oAppointment.Send += _appointment_Send;

    }



    private void _appointment_Send(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Wollen Sie die Veranstaltung per E-Mail verschicken?", "Frage", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)oAppointment).ForwardAsVcal();

            mailItem.Body = "X";

            mailItem.Display();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the warning message you can see the following:

> Warning   1   Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.Send()' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event.Send'. Using method group.

So, to avoid such errors or warnings you can cast the mail item object to the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface:

```
 (mail as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event).Send += AddinModule_Send;
```

If you want to use the `Send` method you need to cast the item object to the [_MailItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.aspx) class instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! That worked! But unfortunately I have another problem now. My program crashes if I hook up the "AfterWrite" event and when I try to send the saved appointment as a attachment. (see the _appointment_send() method). The problem is that even when the "AfterWrite" event is triggered, the Outlook window of the appointment is still open and due to this I think I cannot get access to the saved appointment.